# in tweepy get_authorization_url() locally HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized but in the web works correctly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter, http-status-code-401, tweepy

I am developing with google appengine sdk and python, I'm trying to incorporate my twiiter app

```
import tweepy
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
```

but it does not work, return the following error

```
in get_authorization_url
    raise TweepError(e)
TweepError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

The problem is that this error is generated locally, but the upload my application on the web, works perfectly

Comment: Help me!! saves every change takes a long time

Answer (score 3):

I started digging into the Tweepy code and the error returned was this:

Desktop applications only
support the oauth_callback value \'oob\'

I got around it by setting a callback url in my application. I set mine to 127.0.0.1 and that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me, but Twitter forces the localhost IP address to be prefaced with http://